# Simple OpenGLES 2 vertex shader doesn't works if modify vertex position inside

Tags: c#, opengl-es, opentk

Switching to OpenGLES 2.0 and having a problem with vertex shader. If I'm not correcting vertex position inside of the shader and specify vertexes in (-1) - 1 scope, everything works fine and I see my triangle, but when I try to modify position I'm getting blank screen. Take a look at code, please and tell me if I'm an idiot.

```
static float[] squareVertices2 = {
        512f, 0f, 0.0f,
        1024f, 768f, 0.0f,
        0f, 768f, 0.0f
    };
```

parallel projection

```
projection[0] = 2 / 1024;
projection[1] = (2 / 768);
projection[2] = 1;
projection[3] = -1;
```

getting handles

```
int m_a_positionHandle = GL.GetAttribLocation(CurrentShaderProgram, "a_position");
int m_a_colorHandle = GL.GetAttribLocation(CurrentShaderProgram, "a_color");
int m_u_mvpHandle = GL.GetUniformLocation(CurrentShaderProgram, "uv_Projection");
```

using

```
GL.UseProgram(CurrentShaderProgram);
GL.VertexAttribPointer(m_a_positionHandle, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float , false, 0, squareVertices2);
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(m_a_positionHandle);
GL.VertexAttribPointer(m_a_colorHandle, 4, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, squareColors);
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(m_a_colorHandle);
GL.Uniform4(m_u_mvpHandle, projection[0], projection[1], projection[2], projection[3]);

GL.DrawArrays(BeginMode.Triangles, 0, 3);
```

shader source:

```
@"uniform vec4 uv_Projection;

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;

varying vec4 v_color;

void main()
{
gl_Position = vec4(a_position.xy * uv_Projection.xy, a_position.z, a_position.w);
v_color = a_color;
}"
```

I'm using C# with OpenTK on Windows platform.
Any help is appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found out what was wrong. Actually, there was a problem with math and I was getting nearly zero values of vector positions. Counted parallel projection a bit different and made changed shader to:

```
gl_Position = vec4(a_position.xy * uv_proj.xy + uv_proj.zw, 0, 1);
```

Thanks everyone for reply

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You need to multiply the projection matrix with the full-vector of the position, not only the `xy` values.</strike>

```
gl_Position = modelViewMatrix * a_Position;
```

*Copied from my vertex shader which is working*

#### Edit

I just saw you're using a vector for multiply the position with, i would stick to a matrix first and switch to vectors later when you know that everything is working. Keep it simple until you know that everything is correct working, then optimize.

I personaly use a full matrix for UI-displaying but i modify z and w too:

```
gl_Position = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position.xy, -3, 1);
```

Comment: Why can't I make it just with XY values ? The result should be the same.

Comment: @JacksonRR Right i did not see that you are just using a vector which is a bit different. I don't know what is exactly wrong, but i would start using a matrix first for the projection and switch to a less complex mechanism later ( Because matrices are well known and if any error occurs you know its not the projection formula ).